# how to change notification background color in nougat?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat, android-notification.mediastyle

How do i change notification background in android?

I am using `androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat` and below code work for Oreo and above Oreo device but not working for below Oreo devices.

```
 builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PlayerEngineService.this, R.color.colorBlack))
            .setColorized(true);
```

I make custom notification `View` with black background. But other then notification view notification background is white.

[Right it's look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uveNd.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can customize all your notification UI, This will work for all device. Try these tus:

- [This one](http://tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-notification-background-colour-in-android)
- [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)

Comment: If you check my code notification UI is already custom. but surrounded that UI background color not change

Comment: Just checked again. Look like setColor() and setColorized only works for O and above.

Comment: Yes that's why i am looking for something that work for android 6 and 7 as well.